WebSocket Stuck at ‘Starting on Port 6001’ and Real-Time Chat Not Updating for Receiver
I am trying to make a real-time chat app in Laravel/PHP using Redis, WebSocket, and Pusher, but I have been facing several errors. Right now, when I run:
$ php artisan websockets:serve 

it gets stuck with the message:
Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...

Broadcasting.php
<?php

return [


    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'redis'),
    //'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'pusher'),


    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            // 'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'key' => "e5f439b12032cb8f7894",
            // 'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'secret' => "67e5919f5f17937bf3b6",
            // 'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'app_id' => 1837219,
            'options' => [
                // 'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'cluster' => "mt1",
                'useTLS' => true,
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST'),
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT'),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME'),
                'encrypted' => true
            ],
        ],



        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];


database.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'search_path' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            // 'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'false'),
        ],

    ],


    'migrations' => 'migrations',


    'redis' => [

        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_',
        ],

        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],

        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],

    ],



];


cache.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [


    'default' => env('CACHE_DRIVER', 'redis'),


    'stores' => [

        'apc' => [
            'driver' => 'apc',
        ],

        'array' => [
            'driver' => 'array',
            'serialize' => false,
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'cache',
            'connection' => null,
            'lock_connection' => null,
        ],

        'file' => [
            'driver' => 'file',
            'path' => storage_path('framework/cache/data'),
        ],

        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'cache',
            'lock_connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'dynamodb' => [
            'driver' => 'dynamodb',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
            'table' => env('DYNAMODB_CACHE_TABLE', 'cache'),
            'endpoint' => env('DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT'),
        ],

        'octane' => [
            'driver' => 'octane',
        ],

    ],


    'prefix' => env('CACHE_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_cache_'),

];


queue.php
<?php

return [


    //'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'redis'),
    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'pusher'),



    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 0,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'suffix' => env('SQS_SUFFIX'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],


    ],


    'failed' => [
        'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database-uuids'),
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];


websocket.php
<?php

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Dashboard\Http\Middleware\Authorize;

return [


    'dashboard' => [
        'port' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT', 6001),
    ],

    'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
        ],
    ],


    'app_provider' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Apps\ConfigAppProvider::class,

    'allowed_origins' => [
        //
    ],


    'max_request_size_in_kb' => 250,

    'path' => 'laravel-websockets',

    'middleware' => [
        'web',
        Authorize::class,
    ],

    'statistics' => [

        'model' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Models\WebSocketsStatisticsEntry::class,

        'logger' => BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Statistics\Logger\HttpStatisticsLogger::class,

        'interval_in_seconds' => 60,

        'delete_statistics_older_than_days' => 60,

        'perform_dns_lookup' => false,
    ],

    'ssl' => [

        'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

        'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),

        'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),
    ],


    'channel_manager' => \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Channels\ChannelManagers\ArrayChannelManager::class,
];


app.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

return [

     'api_key' => env('API_KEY', 'Laravel'),

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL'),

    'timezone' => 'Asia/Tokyo',

    'locale' => 'ja',

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',


    'faker_locale' => 'ja_JP',

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',



    'maintenance' => [
        'driver' => 'file',
        // 'store'  => 'redis',
    ],


    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,

        Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,

    ],


    'aliases' => Facade::defaultAliases()->merge([
        'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        // 'ExampleClass' => App\Example\ExampleClass::class,
    ])->toArray(),


];


.env
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_CLIENT=predis
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_DB=0
REDIS_CACHE_DB=1


I solved this problem before somehow, but even though I don’t have any errors with WebSocket, I haven’t succeeded in getting real-time chat to work.
To test the real-time chat function, I opened two different browsers with different users. On the sender's chat screen, when the sender sends a message, it immediately reflects in the chat without refreshing the browser. However, on the receiver's chat screen, the received message doesn't reflect unless the browser is refreshed.
But first, I want to solve the problem with WebSocket connection...
bootstrap.js

        import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';

console.log('Bootstrap.js loaded successfully');
window.Pusher = Pusher;
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
     encrypted: true,
     wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST,
     wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
     wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT,
     forceTLS: false,
     enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
 });

const peopleId = import.meta.env.VITE_PEOPLE_ID || window.peopleId; 

window.Echo.private(`chat.${peopleId}`)
    .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
        console.log('Message received:', e);
        displayMessage(e.chat.message, e.chat.user_identifier, e.chat.user_name, e.chat.created_at, e.chat.filename);
    });

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher(import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY, {
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
channel.bind('App\\Events\\TestEvent', function(data) {
    console.log('Received event:', data);
    console.log('Calling displayMessage function...');
    if (typeof window.displayMessage === 'function') {
        window.displayMessage(data.message, data.user_identifier, data.user_name, data.created_at, data.filename);
    } else {
        console.error('window.displayMessage is not defined');
    }
});



I think there is a connection problem , both  user need  same connection to chat

It has been a while for me sinse i worked with this package. How are you testing this code? I mean i always used js(echo) to subscribe to the channels and once both users subscribe to same channel, thats when the communication works. However, i dont see you mention any js code.
